# select distinct values from all columns

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select only distinct values from each column. Not distinct combination.
Here is my query but its returning distinct combination of all columns. i want that each column show its own distinct values without depending on other columns.

```
 $sql= "select distinct
            CASE WHEN col1 not regexp '[0-9]' THEN col1 else null end as col1
            ,CASE WHEN col2 not regexp '[0-9]' THEN col2 else null end as col2
            ,CASE WHEN col3 not regexp '[0-9]' THEN col3 else null end as col3 from table_name";
```

It returns this:

```
col1| col2| col3
a      1     3
b      2     4
c      2     4
d      1     3
```

you guys could see that the values of col2 and col3 are not distinct i want only distinct from col2 and col3 too. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on `but not working`?  Can you show us sample data and what your desired output is?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen check it now hope you will get it.

Comment: Distinct works across all columns, not individually in them, in the case of `distinct col1, col2, col3` ... and your `case` stmt does not impact that

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help us understand what you want.

Comment: @Drew so i want to select distinct values of all col1, col2, col3 separately. not the distinct combination of all these columns.

Comment: Well not my downvote as it is a question that confuses a lot of people

Comment: @ drew sorry check it out updated version.

Comment: If you put a space after the @ I will never see it. Are you all set with this question?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess as to what you want is to use `union all`:

```
select distinct (case when col1 not regexp '[0-9]' then col1 end) as col1, 'col1' as which
from table_name
union all
select distinct (case when col2 not regexp '[0-9]' then col2 end) as col2, 'col2' as which
from table_name
union all
select distinct (case when col3 not regexp '[0-9]' then col3 end) as col3, 'col3' as which
from table_name;
```

This produces a result with two columns, one is the column name and the other is a distinct value in the column.

Comment: its not working. simple is that i want distinct values from all columns separately. hope you get it.

Comment: If you showed Gordon some sample data you have, and Expected Results, he could do this in his sleep